# Cambiar idioma Español o de NetBeans sin reinstalar

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el idioma de la interfaz gráfica de netbeans de inglés a castellano sin reinstalar?

Traté modificando el archivo de configuración ubicado en

```
etc/netbeans.conf
```

En la variable `netbeans_default_options` agregué el parámetro `-J-Duser.language=es` pero no funcionó

Esta es mi línea actual:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Duser.language=es -J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Xss2m -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-Djdk.gtk.version=2.2 -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-modules=jdk.jshell -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.javadoc/com.sun.tools.javadoc.main=ALL-UNNAMED -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"
```

Comment: Sobre qué sistema operativo corres netbeans?

Comment: El OS es Windows 10

Comment: Revisa si te sirve [este enlace](https://touchgamez.com/netbeans/)

Comment: Tu estas seguro de que se puede?yo creo queno

Comment: sí se puede pero ya no compartí la solución por no ser nada convencional :P

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que estás en alguna distro linux por la ubicación del archivo, podrías probar lo que sugieren en [esta respuesta](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231361/how-to-change-the-netbeans-ide-language) de AskUbuntu.

Los pasos a seguir son:

1. Revisar que el locale para español que quieres usar esté en tu máquina. Para eso puedes usar

   ```
   $ locale -a
   ```

que dará una lista de los que están instalados, disponibles.

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_AT.utf8
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
...
POSIX
```

2. Si no está el que deseas usar, revisa en el archivo `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` y genera los locales en la máquina para el locale que deseas usar:

   ```
   sudo locale-gen es_ES # o es_EC, es_AR,...
   sudo locale-gen es_ES.UTF-8
   ```
3. Desde la terminal, probar `LC_ALL=es_ES.utf8 netbeans`. Si el comando funciona, puedes crear un launcher nuevo con exactamente ese comando

Comment: Me gustaría cambiar el locale del programa, no de todo el sistema operativo. Gracias

Comment: Este procedimiento no cambia el locale de todo el OS