# ¿Cómo cambiarle el idioma de neatbeans?

Tags: java

hace unos años encontré un tutorial sobre como poner el idioma en español, japones o ruso al ide NetBeans a través de un plugin, pero ahora ya no encuentro ese tutorial y no lo documente para poder hacerlo de nuevo en el futuro.
alguien sabes como hacerlo?

Comment: Hola  Anderson, bienvenido, mira [aquí]( https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/278379/cambiar-idioma-espa%C3%B1ol-o-de-netbeans-sin-reinstalar) puede que te sirva.