# Cambiar el idioma de la interfaz gráfica a español de Apache Netbeans IDE 12.0 instalado en Windows

Tags: windows11, netbeans-12

tengo instalado Apache Netbeans IDE 12.0 en Windows 11.

¿Se puede cambiar el idioma de la interfaz gráfica a español?

He intentado hacerlo modificando en el fichero `netbeans.conf` que está en la ruta `C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.0\netbeans\etc` la variable `netbeans_default_options` incluyendo el parámetro `-J-Duser.language=es -J-Duser.region=ES`.

Queda de la siguiente forma:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Duser.language=es -J-Duser.region=ES...
```

Pero al iniciar netbeans de nuevo continúa en inglés.

¿Me falta algún paso?, ¿se hace de otra manera? o ¿simplemente no se puede cambiar el idioma?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tal vez [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/278379/cambiar-idioma-espa%c3%b1ol-o-de-netbeans-sin-reinstalar) te sirva

Comment: me parece que en las versiones más recientes habían quitado el archivo con la traducción al castellano en la versión propietaria, y ahora con el paso a apache sinceramente no he podido hallar los archivos con las traducciones.

Comment: @Alfabravo, gracias, pero si te fijas es lo que yo hago y no funciona. Como parece que se quedó muerto he preguntado.

Comment: @RuslanLópez López entonces parece que habrá que quedarse en inglés...